# Problem with execute command in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to run this command:

```
execute @a[score_hammer_min=1,score_shift_min=1,score_attack_min=1,rx=74,rxm=90] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
```

I have tried changing the variables around and taking away the forward slashes or putting them in different places but it's still not working.

I was trying to get the player to summon a lighting bolt depending on their rotation and a few variables, but it just says `invalid entity UUID format`.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Worked for me after creating and setting those objectives. You have the values of `rx` and `rxm` the wrong way around I believe, although this seems to just allow any direction rather than not finding a player.

Comment: hmmm it must have been a problem with my variable names then. Let me double check

Comment: i tried again and its still not working... If it helps the hammer variable is set to 1 based on whether you have a wooden axe in your hand and the attack tests for an item in a specific slot. Also the shift variable is just set to cm moved while crouched. These are being set to 0 on a slowish clock and then reset. The command that i used in the above thing is going on an extremely fast clock though.

Comment: what version did you try it in?

Comment: 1.8.4. Try removing the clock that sets them to 0 and then set them all to 1 manually. The problem does not seem to be with the command you have posted.

Comment: still didn't work. could it maybe be a bug?

Comment: Check each of the objectives separately to make sure they are all actually at 1. Perhaps you could also upload the world somewhere?

Comment: This is not a bug. This generally happens when the syntax is incorrect. I don't see anything wrong with your syntax, but I didn't either earlier today. I had to use a different method if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the scores's capitals; `score_Hammer_min=1,score_Shift_min=1,score_Attack_min=1`

And also are you sure you aren't in a team (/scoreboard teams) or created the right objectives?

Check for any grammar mistakes, your problem could be that.

Comment: The target selector arguments for the score have exactly the same capitalization as the objective itself, and OP has already double-checked both the objectives and the spelling, as confirmed in one of his comments.

Comment: yeah i have checked

Comment: and I'm sure i used scoreboard players

Comment: i will upload the world and post the link here

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/jvxd2kw254oy5w1/Thor!.zip